How to see "IMAGE LAYERS" for a previous version of an image in hub.docker.com?
The context
I am a beginner MongoDB and Docker user. I'm learning how to run MongoDB on Docker. I have found this guide in the MongoDB's official documentation which suggests downloading the Docker image by running the following

Pull the MongoDB Docker Image
docker pull mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest

A few weeks ago, I executed that command (see proof below)
docker image ls -a

REPOSITORY                         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mongodb/mongodb-community-server   latest    46a7ea3f9063   3 weeks ago   1.17GB

Out of curiosity, I want to find the commands that were used to build the specific image mongodb/mongodb-community-server that was installed on my system when I run docker pull some weeks ago.
This is the link to the image mongodb/mongodb-community-server in hub.docker.com. I opened the Tags tab for that image in hub.docker.com (link). I then found the tag latest (link) and I can see that the IMAGE LAYERS show some Docker commands (see screenshot below.) which I believe are the commands for building that image. However, those commands correspond to a version of an image that was pushed 17 hours ago. I want to see that information but for the image on my system that was installed on my system. I know the commands might be similar, but I want to still see those commands.

The question
My question is: How to see the IMAGE LAYERS presented on docker.hub.com but for a previous version of a given image?

Find the SHA of your image and use that in the link... https://hub.docker.com/layers/mongodb/mongodb-community-server/latest/images/sha256-<sha-goes-here>

You might also be interested in the actual Dockerfile

The web page is populated from the image config json, specifically the history section. That history content can be viewed in already pulled images with docker image history, e.g.:
$ docker image history mariadb                                                                                                                                                                                     
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT                                                                                                                    
bc6434c28e9a   2 months ago   CMD ["mariadbd"]                                0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     
<missing>      2 months ago   EXPOSE map[3306/tcp:{}]                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     
<missing>      2 months ago   ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]             0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     
<missing>      2 months ago   COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/ # …   26.1kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     
<missing>      2 months ago   COPY healthcheck.sh /usr/local/bin/healthche…   9.24kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     <missing>      2 months ago   VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0    
<missing>      2 months ago   RUN |3 GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F165…   312MB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   RUN |3 GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F165…   133B      buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   ARG REPOSITORY=http://archive.mariadb.org/ma…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   ENV MARIADB_VERSION=1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204      0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   ARG MARIADB_VERSION=1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204      0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0               
<missing>      2 months ago   LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors=Maria…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     <missing>      2 months ago   ENV LANG=C.UTF-8                                0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     <missing>      2 months ago   RUN |1 GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F165…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0                                                                                                     <missing>      2 months ago   RUN |1 GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F165…   14.5MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0      
<missing>      2 months ago   ARG GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F2…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.17                           0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   RUN /bin/sh -c groupadd -r mysql && useradd …   329kB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0       
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B                                                                                                                                   
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:21c2e8d95909bec6f…   77.9MB                                                                                                                               
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.opencontainers.…   0B                                                                                                                                   
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL org.opencontainers.…   0B                                                                                                                                   
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG LAUNCHPAD_BUILD_ARCH     0B                                                                                                                                   
<missing>      2 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG RELEASE                  0B   

And for lines that are longer than the column, you can use --no-trunc to see the full line.
